# Export the list content type data to CSV in sharepoint using powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I'm working on exporting the data from list content type data to CSV. I'm able to pull the data to CSV but it is coming with some garbage values from the field links.

```
$url = "http://mysite/abc"
$listName = "Issues"
$web = Get-SPWeb $url
$list = $web.Lists.TryGetList($listName)
$fields = $list.ContentTypes | %{ $_.FieldLinks } 
$items = @() #array to store objects representing list items
$list.Items | %{
  $item = $_; 
  $hash = @{}; #hash table to store field name-value pairs
  $fields | %{ $hash[$_.DisplayName] = $item[$_.DisplayName] }; 
  $items += New-Object PSObject -Property $hash
}
$items | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Temp\test2.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

and output contains some bad values with data, I'm copying two field values:

```
<div class="ExternalClass756614A031B94F15B792C243E62683BA"><p>?Vacations rearranged to remove conflict.&#160; No impact to project schedule</p></div>
```

and

```
string;#121 - Vacation schedules are conflicting
```

Comment: Try to find out where they come from (which item, which field), then clean them out when you fill the hashtable.

Comment: They are coming from xml of $item which they are covered with ' ' as values. I'm struggling to differentiate the actual values with garbage as each time they are different. and finally  I have to export the list content type data from more subsites and put them into csv.

Comment: How do you expect us to help you with that when you don't give us an input sample with a definition of what you do and don't consider to be "garbage" in that sample?